# Xelement to expanded empty tags

Tags: c#, .net, xml, sharepoint, xelement

I am generating XML in my c#, when I have few empty tags for example,

```
 new XElement("TransLogID", "")
```

some of those gets rendered as

```
<TransLogID></TransLogID>
```

while some of those gets rendered as

```
<TransLogID/>
```

What controls when the tags will be expanded and when not? How can I force them to be in a behavior I want?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think they have different origins.

```
Root.Add(new XElement("TransLogID1", ""));
Root.Add(new XElement("TransLogID2"));
```

will give

```
<TransLogID1></TransLogID1>
<TransLogID2/>
```

Both elements will have empty Elements/Nodes collections, the subtle difference is that the TransLogID2 will have IsEmpty=true.

Answer (score 6):

If your content is an empty string (`new XElement("TransLogID", "")`), it will render as

```
<TransLogID></TransLogID>
```

But if it is null (`new XElement("TransLogID", null)`), it will render as

```
<TransLogID/>
```

Are you sure you're always generating the nodes the same way?